# remove_cap nothing changes

Tags: user-roles

I have been trying to disable the possibility that a specific user with Role Editor can edit post, read and publish posts I have this code but when verifying remains the same

```
function set_capabilities() {

    $user = new WP_User( 9 );

    $caps = array('edit_posts', 'publish_posts', 'read');

    $user->remove_cap( $caps );
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_capabilities' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `remove_cap` method from `WP_User` class-

```
/**
 * Remove capability from user.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 * @access public
 *
 * @param string $cap Capability name.
 */
public function remove_cap( $cap ) {
    if ( ! isset( $this->caps[ $cap ] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    unset( $this->caps[ $cap ] );
    update_user_meta( $this->ID, $this->cap_key, $this->caps );
    $this->get_role_caps();
    $this->update_user_level_from_caps();
}
```

Here at the documentation it is said that the parameter must be string. But you passed array. So the updated code should be like below-

```
function the_dramatist_set_capabilities() {
    $user = new WP_User( 9 );
    $caps = array('edit_posts', 'publish_posts', 'read');
    foreach ($caps as $cap) {
        $user->remove_cap( $cap );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'the_dramatist_set_capabilities' );
```

Hope the above code will fix your problem. And always prefix your function with a unique keyword like here I've prefixed it with ***the_dramatist_***.

Comment: I am sorry! but it does not work

Comment: Have a look on the user's capabilities who posses the ID 9. Make sure that the user have the 'edit_posts', 'publish_posts', 'read' capabilities.